# how to return data from angular HttpInterceptor and access in another angular component

Tags: angular, angular-observable

i have an HttpInterceptor which is calculating total time "totalTimeTakenByRequest" for a request and response and i want to display this information on a UI component . how can i do this?
My angular interceptor is :

```
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor
{
    totalTimeTakenByRequest:number=0;
       constructor() {`enter code here`
                     }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
    const started = Date.now()
  return next.handle(req).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
          const elapsed = Date.now() - started;
          this.totalTimeTakenByRequest=elapsed;
      }))
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's the best solution, but you can store the value into a separated service. Inject this service into your component and just get the value.

Comment: i am new to angular , you may share if there is any best solution .
actually i implemented what you suggested but it doesn't display the first value from the interceptor and displays subsequent response times .

Comment: I guess you're overwriting your previous values, as you have just one interceptor for all your requests. What if you out these values into an array?
`this.totalTimeService.totalTimes.push(elapsed)`
Then you could render all these values in the component you wish

Comment: that won't override because we are only executing only one request and response at a time .

Comment: the question here is how can i get "totalTimeTakenByRequest" in another component . currently i am setting the value in a variable belong to another service injected here in this interceptor and getting value in my desired component but only values after the second request. the first request populates no response time in this variable .

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, you want to show request processing time from your `InterceptorService` to component.

Below is the code for sharing data between `components` and `services` using `Subject` operator from `rxjs`. Also, you can `Behaviour` operator as well if you want to set initial value.

**1. app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InterceptorService } from './services/interceptor.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
    providers: [
               { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
                 useClass: InterceptorService, 
                 multi: true 
               }],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**2. app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataShareService } from './services/data-share.service';
import { HttpService } from './services/http.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
   title = 'TestStack';
   elapsedTime: any = '';
   data: any = '';

   constructor(private dataShareService: DataShareService, private httpService : HttpService){
        this.dataShareService.SharingData.subscribe((res: any) => {  
        this.elapsedTime = res;  
    });
  }

  GetData(){
    this.httpService.getData().subscribe((res : any) => {
    this.data = res;
    });
  }
}
```

**3. app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="GetData()">Get Data</button>
{{elapsedTime}}
<h2>Header Example</h2>
<pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>
```

**Services & Interceptor**

**1. interceptor.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { DataShareService } from './data-share.service';

@Injectable()
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private dataShareService : DataShareService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const started = Date.now()
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
      const elapsed = Date.now() - started;
      this.dataShareService.SharingData.next(elapsed);
    }))
  }
}
```

**2. data-share.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';  

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataShareService {

  SharingData = new Subject();  
  constructor() { }
}
```

**3. http.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getData(){
    return this.httpClient.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  }
}
```

**Note:**

For API calling, I have used **JsonPlaceHolder** free api for demo.

Working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/interceptordatasharedemo).